# Facebook Link doesnt work android

Tags: android, facebook

Hello I just want to call Facebook app with the link below (on my android project):

```
String url_facebook_prixo = "https://www.facebook.com/pages/Prixo/468580313168290";
```

I tried this :

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("facebook://facebook.com/page{468580313168290}");
                            Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(viewIntent);
```

I tried with others link but its only displaying my wall..

Someone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the id to open the page.

```
Intent facebookIntent = new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("fb://profile/468580313168290"));
startActivity(facebookIntent);
```

I would advice you to encapsulate this in a try catch. Inside the catch open a normal browser intent